# Spark concurrency on EMR cluster with multiple jobs

Tags: apache-spark, concurrency, amazon-emr

I have a small EMR cluster with

3 `m5.2xlarge` core nodes

1 `m5.2xlarge` master node.

Since each `m5.2xlarge` has 8 cores and 32 GB memory, essentially my available cores are `3 * 8 = 24` and the available memory is `3 * 32Gb = 96Gb`.
As per some online recommendations, I am leaving 1 core per node for the driver processes, hence my number of available cores comes down to `3 * 8 - 3 = 21`

Now, I am deploying 4 concurrent spark jobs on this cluster, and for each one of them I am setting the `--num-executors = 7`, `--executor-cores = 3` and `--executor-memory = 10G`.
I am curious to know your thoughts on this and whether this is good idea.
I'd think this is a good idea if there was only single spark job running at the time, but should I devide everything by 4, given that 4 parallel and separate spark jobs are running at a given time?

Also, when the jobs are running, I can see in the spark UI that for each one of jobs there is 3 executors available (one driver and two cores). This makes me confused, since it means that EMR has 12 executors (and possibly 36 cores?) at a given time, 3 for each of my jobs. But this should not happen since the availble number of total cores can be 24 tops.

Any advise on this would be much appreciated!
Thank you !